# How to change settings and application folders in VSCode

Tags: synchronization, visual-studio-code, directory, settings

Is it possible to change these folders for Visual Studio Code?

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.vscode 

C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Code
```

I want these folders to be on one custom place. I want to sync these folders with Google Drive for example. I dont want to use extensions, this is no option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a symlink ([using the `mklink` command](https://superuser.com/a/1020825/365386)) for this, no need for VSCode to explicitly support it ([I don't think it does at the moment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22557)).

For instance, I use a symlink to share the installed extensions between VSCode and VSCode Insiders, meaning that my:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.vscode-insiders\extensions
```

folder is a symlink that points to

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.vscode\extensions
```

---

To do this, I ran the following in a `cmd`:

```
mklink /D C:\Users\<USER>\.vscode-insiders\extensions C:\Users\<USER>\.vscode\extensions
```

Of course, you could just as well have a symlink point to some folder inside your Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea how to solve this problem, i will try it.